# How can I change the date and time on Ubuntu?

Tags: time, date

When I go to change the date and time it doesn't work. I try to unlock but it just won't unlock. If there is any way to make it work please help.

I know it isn't very descriptive but I really would appreciate some answers.

Comment: `timedatectl set-ntp yes`

Answer (score 97):

From [`man date`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/date.1.html)

```
-s, --set=STRING
          set time described by STRING
```

To change date, use the command in terminal,

```
sudo date --set=STRING
```

For example, to change date to **25 Sep 2013 15:00**, the command would be,

```
sudo date --set "25 Sep 2013 15:00:00"
```

Comment: Does it also work if system is rebooted or it has to be apply every time after reboot?

Comment: Yes, it works after system reboot; you wouldn't have to apply it every time.

Comment: After reboot system is automatically picking current date.

Comment: If the date appears to be something way wrong after a reboot or power cycle, it usually means the battery on the motherboard is bad.

Comment: This appears to no longer work. Using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Teekin you should probably mention the error you receive. Works fine on 17.10

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, sorry, I should have mentioned, but there was no error message.

Comment: On 16.04 LTS, in Time & Date (System Settings), set the time **manually**. If not, the command is executed, but the date and the time are not changed.

Comment: It worked for 18.04 LTS

Comment: not working. set date by `sudo date --set=STRING` result printed that date has changed but actually date is not changed.

Answer (score 78):

Try this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

This both lets you configure your timezone (you may just pick the same), and automagically synchronizes your time.

If there's no tzdata package, install it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tzdata
```

Comment: This solve my Ubuntu server timezone setting, thank you.

Answer (score 16):

In 12.04 I don't have to Unlock anything.  Just click on the clock on the top bar, and choose Time & Date Settings, once the Time & Date window opens, choose Manually, so you can change the time and date manually; otherwise choose your time zone from the map, and 
choose Automatic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not able to change my system's time this way. I can change the time from the settings but it is not reflecting on my top bar.

Comment: It takes a while (+30 secs), but the top bar does update after sometime. (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: You'll have to change the focus of the Date spinner control to have the date changed immediately. Very odd :)   (Ubuntu 14.10)

Comment: None of these solutions work for me, am on 14.04 as well.

Comment: sometimes to reflect the settings changes you need to kill unity panel service and restart it. Click clock on the top bar, and choose Time & Date Settings
once the Time & Date window opens
choose Manually so you can change the time and date manually; otherwise choose your time zone from the map, and choose Automatically. Now to reflect changes instantly open terminal and type
killall unity-panel-service

Answer (score 9):

See [this blog post](https://codeghar.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/manage-time-in-ubuntu-through-command-line/) for setting the date with a machine-friendly format string:

```
sudo date 120622432007.55
```

for December 6, 2007, 22:43:55,

and see [this answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1759114) for setting the date with a human-friendly string:

```
sudo date --set "15 MAY 2011 1:40 PM"
```

Comment: Thank you :) That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to change the time zone only, refer to this:

- [How to change timezone on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-timezone-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Therefore

1. Check Current Timezone Settings: `$ timedatectl`
2. Show all Available Timezones: `$ timedatectl list-timezones`
3. Change Timezone: `$ sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Berlin`.

Answer (score 3):

To change the date and time to a fixed value on an Ubuntu version using `timesyncd`, do the following.

Stop `timesyncd`:

```
sudo systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd
```

Set the date and/or time manually:

```
sudo timedatectl set-time 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

Or:

```
sudo timedatectl set-time 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

When you want to revert to the current time and date, run:

```
sudo systemctl start systemd-timesyncd
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue on my install and the above command gave this error:

```
date: the argument '19 Sep 2014 20:11:00' lacks a leading '+';
when using an option to specify date(s), any non-option
argument must be a format string beginning with '+'
Try 'date --help'
```

Help shows -

```
Usage: date [option]...  [+FORMAT] - (etc)
```

Added the required *plus* as indicated to render `+19 Sep 2014 20:11:00` which worked.

Comment: This is for _displaying_ the date, not _setting_ it.