# Time issue on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: time, timezone

[image: Screenshot comparing time shown by Google with time shown by sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata]

The time on my machine is wrong.  I have exhausted almost all the popular solutons without success.  I am not able to change the time even manually through settings.

I dual boot with Windows 10.

Comment: If [the solutions there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot) don't help, please **[edit]** to explain.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it if automatic time synchronization is disabled:

```
sudo timedatectl set-time '10:42:43'
```

Otherwise, use:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

and follow onscreen instructions. You can read more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349763/how-can-i-change-the-date-and-time-on-ubuntu).